# Mapping Values of key in Dictionary present in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe A with column 'col_1' and values of column is A and B and and I am trying to map the values of A and B present in Dictionary

DataFrame A:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP9Rh.png)

and have dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb1EC.png)

and I want the output like this

Dataframe :

col_1  Values

1. A      1
2. A      2
3. A      3
4. B      1
5. B      2

Any help will be highly appreciated
thanks

Comment: The values should something A spaced by the number from the duct ie A 1. Is that what you mean? If not make it organise the sample data above

Comment: yes ,I want to create a new column 'Values' which has a value of A and B preset in dictionary

Comment: Did you try out what I uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to frame your problem properly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_1":["A","A","A","B","B"]})
```

Printing `df` gives us your `dataframe` shown in the image above:

```
print(df)

    col_1
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     B
4     B
```

Here is your dictionary:

```
dict1 = {"A":[1,2,3], "B":[1,2]}
```

I created an empty `list` to hold the elements then stack up the `list` with your request, and finally created a new `column` called `values` and write the `list` into the `column`

```
values1 = []

for key,value_list in dict1.items():
    for item in value_list:
        value_item = key+" "+ str(item)
        values1.append(value_item)

df["values"] = values1
```

printing `df` results into:

```
df


     col_1  values
0     A      A 1
1     A      A 2
2     A      A 3
3     B      B 1
4     B      B 2
```

Comment: Thank u so much Pankaj...This is how I wanted the output..Really appreciated...I am new to stackover flow..need guidance how to post question like a coding in python.

Comment: Can you accept the answer. You want me to help out on your PC?

Comment: how will I do it